# Mapping Regular Data Types to ClickHouse JDBC Supported Data Types in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, jdbc, clickhouse

I'm currently working on a Kotlin/Java/Gradle project where I'm interfacing with ClickHouse using their JDBC driver. I'm writing a function that generates a ClickHouse file based on a given list of columns with associated data types.

My primary issue is with the mapping of regular data types to the supported ClickHouse data types via the JDBC driver. I currently have a mapping as follows:

```
val dataTypes = mapOf(
    "int" to "Int32",
    "float" to "Decimal32(2)",
    "float64" to "Decimal64(2)",
    "boolean" to "Bool",
    "string" to "String",
    "date" to "Date",
    "datetime" to "DateTime"
)
```

This mapping does not cover all the data types that the ClickHouse JDBC driver supports, and I'm struggling to create a comprehensive and accurate mapping between the regular data types and these supported data types. The supported data types are:

- Array(*)
- Bool
- Date*
- DateTime*
- Decimal*
- Enum*
- Geo Types (Point, Ring, Polygon, and MultiPolygon)
- Int*, UInt* (UInt64 is mapped to long)
- IPv*
- Map(*)
- Nested(*)
- Object('JSON')
- SimpleAggregateFunction
- *String
- Tuple(*)
- UUID

Specifically, I'm facing issues when dealing with float, decimal, and date and datetime data types. I'm not sure about the best practices to handle these types in ClickHouse and I'd appreciate any guidance on how to map these types properly.

In addition, I'm looking for advice on handling specific edge cases, such as how to handle the UUID generation for 'increment' generator columns, and the proper casting of the different ClickHouse data types when inserting the values into the table.

Here is the function I'm working on for reference:

```
override fun getGeneratedFileClickhouse(file: File, rows: Int, columns: List<ColumnSettings>, tableName: String): InputStreamResource {

        val dummyTable = getGeneratedList(rows, columns)
        val tableName = tableName
        val columnNames = columns.joinToString(", ") { it.name }
        val dataTypes = mapOf(
            "int" to "Int32",
            "float" to "Decimal32(2)",
            "float64" to "Decimal64(2)",
            "boolean" to "Bool",
            "string" to "String",
            "date" to "Date",
            "datetime" to "DateTime"
        )



        try {
            val writer = FileWriter(file)

            // Generate the CREATE TABLE statement
            writer.write("CREATE TABLE $tableName (\n")
            var primaryKey = ""
            for (column in columns) {
                val dataType = dataTypes[column.dataType]
                writer.write("  ${column.name} $dataType")
                if (column.generator == "increment") {
                    if (column.dataType != "int") {
                        throw IllegalArgumentException("The 'increment' generator can only be applied to 'int' columns. Column '${column.name}' has dataType '${column.dataType}'.")
                    }
                    writer.write(" DEFAULT generateUUIDv4()")
                    primaryKey = column.name
                }
                writer.write(",\n")
            }


            if (primaryKey.isNotEmpty()) {
                writer.write("  PRIMARY KEY ($primaryKey)\n")
                writer.write(") ENGINE = MergeTree ORDER BY $primaryKey;\n\n")
            } else {
                writer.write(") ENGINE = MergeTree();\n\n")  // no ORDER BY
            }

            // Generate the INSERT INTO statements
            for ((indexRow, row) in dummyTable.withIndex()) {

                // Head line with column names
                if (indexRow == 0) continue

                writer.write("INSERT INTO $tableName ($columnNames) VALUES (")
                for ((index, column) in columns.withIndex()) {
                    val value = when (dataTypes[column.dataType]) {
                        "Int32" -> row.fields[index].toInt()
                        "Decimal32(2)", "Decimal64(2)" -> row.fields[index].toDouble()
                        "Bool" -> if (row.fields[index] == "true") "1" else "0"
                        "String" -> "'${row.fields[index]}'"
                        "Date" -> "toDate('${row.fields[index]}')"
                        "DateTime" -> "toDateTime('${row.fields[index]}')"
                        else -> error("Unknown data type: ${column.dataType}")
                    }


                    writer.write("$value")
                    if (index < columns.count() - 1) writer.write(", ")
                }
                writer.write(");\n")
            }

            writer.close()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        val inputStream = FileInputStream(file)

        return InputStreamResource(inputStream)
    }
}
```

I tried to map my standard data types to the ClickHouse JDBC supported data types using a Kotlin Map.
I've been testing this using a function that generates a ClickHouse file.
I've attempted to handle the generation of UUID for 'increment' generator columns in this function.

I expected that my existing mapping would cover all cases, but it doesn't accommodate all the data types supported by ClickHouse JDBC.
When handling the 'increment' generator columns, I anticipated that the UUID would be generated for each new increment.